# How can I manage Linux settings (config) files in different directories in a single Git repo in another directory?

Tags: linux, git, version-control, centos

Suppose I have 6 different files on different locations which I want to put under one repo.

E.g. I have files like

```
~/bashrc
/etc/php.ini
/etc/apache.conf
/etc/virtualhosts.conf
/scripts/mybackup.sh
```

Now I want to put those in my one repo called `My Scripts` from one location, so that if I use `git status` and then if those files are modified then I can see those from one location.  Can I use symlinks?

Comment: Please use proper capitalization, especially for pronoun "I"!  I edited all of your "i"s to "I"s for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use symlinks. It is indeed what dotfiles managers such as [homesick](https://github.com/technicalpickles/homesick) do. It is helpful to have a script to generate all the links automatically for you, in case you want to clone your setup to another box.

Comment: Not to mention the same box after something that goes horribly wrong.